# Get object from select element on (change) event handler when value is bound to a non-unique prop

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, select

I have a select element from which I want to get object selected on (change) event handler. The catch is that the value of the select element is bound using one of the non unique identifier props of the object.

My list looks something like this:

```
arr = [{prop1:"one", name: "single"}
     , {prop1:"one", name: "double"}
     , {prop1:"two", name:"single"}
     , {prop1:"two", name: "double"}];
```

I know this is a horribly structured list (to not have a unique identifier) and the best solution might be to just restructure the list to include a unique identifier.

But is there a way to get the object selected on the (change) event handler?

```
<select [ngModel]="test" (change)="selectChanged($event.target.value)" name="test">
  <option *ngFor="let obj of arr" value="{{obj.prop1}}">{{obj.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as below.

**HTML**

```
<select (change)="selectChanged($event.target.value)">
  <option *ngFor="let obj of arr" [value]="obj.prop1">{{obj.name}}</option>
</select>
```

**TS**

```
 selectChanged(selected) {
   this.test = this.arr.find((item) => item.prop1 === selected);
   console.log(this.test);
 }
```

**[StackBlitz Demo.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-58925533?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

> **Update**

Another way to get selected `option` is using `ngValue`. You can do it as below.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="test" (change)="selectChanged()" name="test">
  <option *ngFor="let obj of arr" [ngValue]="obj">{{obj.name}}</option>
</select>
```

**[StackBlitz Demo.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dl5cbl)**

Comment: Thanks Sudarshana. But the property prop1 is not a unique identifier. So, I don't think we can use the find operator to retrieve the selected object.

Comment: yes. can you do what you need using updated section in my answer ?

Comment: Yes the object has now been passed. But there is a problem with binding the select element with initialized value of prop1 property.